# Where is XDisplayName declared?

Tags: x11

I borrowed some code from dsimple.c that makes a call to XdisplayName. gcc tells me it is an 'undefined reference'. It seems to be a legitimate call, but I cannot find the header file where it is declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my system it is `X11/Xlib.h`. Are you sure you didn't mistype it? (your post says 'XdisplayName', although the title is correct).

Comment: Yes, it is in the 1998 version of Xlib.h. I was looking at an older version from the web (1988 maybe?) that didn't have it.